# Material Design - where is it?

Tags: android, material-design

saw all the I/O videos on Material Design but where is it?  Where are all the widgets and libraries?  I have 5.0 libraries loaded in Eclipse but the new widgets don't appear and I have the Graphical layout set to 21.

Can we redesign our existing apps that run on older versions to MD?  None of the videos or specs address this.
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the training guide on the Android Developer's website here: https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Material Design isn't a thing, it's an idea. It's a set of guidelines, not a set of widgets. I would start [with the introduction](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-principles) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Material Design is a design language - a concept and a set of guidelines how to design app. API 21 introduces some new features, but it's true that some part of MD exists only in the documentation for designers. Sure you can implement MD using any API on any platform. I'm implementing some of the features for Gingerbread and it's going pretty well.

API 21 introduces the Toolbar class, the vector drawing engine, the Ripple touch feedback, the shadow and elevation engine, the CardView class, the date and time picker, the Palette library, the Window.setStatusBarColor method and several things more.

You can find a lot of information on YouTube channel for Android Developers: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_rbUGf2brcwvZDwziVdtU6